# Displaying loading symbol or ActivityIndicator before AlertView

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In my app when click on save button i need to display a loading symbol until i get `alertView` as:

> Contact saved successfully.

I used `UIActivityIndicator` which is not working.

```
spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorViewalloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[spinner startAnimating];
[alertView addSubview:spinner];
```

Comment: what code you had tried yet?

Comment: in which method you want to show that alert?

Comment: method name is saveContactDetails which will be called when click on save button

Comment: you are showing an alert na,from where you are getting that response like contact added successfully(data base webservice or any where else)?

Comment: it is taking few seconds  to display an alert message.I want to let tell the user that saving processing going on.

Comment: i am getting response from backend(sqlite).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what is exactly your code, but try this where you want to display the animation:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(threadStartAnimating:) toTarget:self withObject:nil]
```

And this is the method to start animation - locate it in the same class.

```
- (void) threadStartAnimating:(id)data {
 spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorViewalloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[spinner startAnimating];
[alertView addSubview:spinner];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set the position of your spinner after `[alertView show]`;
For example: `spinner.center = CGPointMake(alertView.frame.size.width/2,alertView.frame.size.height/2);`